# In JavaFX's FXML, how to declare handlers for custom events?

Tags: java, events, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm designing a custom JavaFX node using FXML. This node fires a custom event.
And I would like to know how to add an event handler to the custom event in the FXML of the parent of this node.

I created my handler, passed it to the child as an object property and hooked it into the event system via the `setEventHandler` method. But it throws me an error when the event is fired.

Custom event code :

```java
public class ValueUpdatedEvent extends Event {

    public static final EventType<ActionEvent> VALUE =
            new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "VALUE_UPDATED");

    private float value;

    public ValueUpdatedEvent() {
        super(VALUE);
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Child component controller :

```java
public class CharacteristicBar extends Component {

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField field;

    @FXML
    private JFXProgressBar bar;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton plus;

    @FXML
    JFXButton minus;

    private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent>> onValueUpdated = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent>>() {
        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return CharacteristicBar.this;
        }


        @Override protected void invalidated() {
            setEventHandler(new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "onValueUpdated"), get());
        }


        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "onValueUpdated";
        }
    };

    private SimpleFloatProperty value = new SimpleFloatProperty();

    private boolean readonly = false;

    public CharacteristicBar() {
        super("CharacteristicBar.fxml");
        value.addListener(
                newValue -> {
                    ValueUpdatedEvent event = new ValueUpdatedEvent();
                    event.setValue(value.get());
                    fireEvent(event);
                }
        );

        bar.progressProperty().bind(this.value);
        if (this.readonly) {
            this.field.setEditable(false);
            this.minus.setVisible(false);
            this.plus.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleInput(KeyEvent event) {
        try {
            value.set(Float.parseFloat(field.getText()) / 20f);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            field.setText("");
        }
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value.get() * 20f;
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleClickPlus(ActionEvent event) {
        this.value.set((this.value.get() * 20f + 1f) / 20f);
        this.field.setText(String.valueOf(this.value.get() * 20));
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleClickMinus(ActionEvent event) {
        this.value.set((this.value.get() * 20f - 1f) / 20f);
        this.field.setText(String.valueOf(this.value.get() * 20));
    }

    public boolean isReadonly() {
        return readonly;
    }

    public void setReadonly(boolean readonly) {
        this.readonly = readonly;
        this.field.setEditable(!readonly);
        this.minus.setVisible(!readonly);
        this.plus.setVisible(!readonly);
    }

    public EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent> getOnValueUpdated() {
        return onValueUpdated.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent>> onValueUpdatedProperty() {
        return onValueUpdated;
    }

    public void setOnValueUpdated(EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent> onValueUpdated) {
        this.onValueUpdated.set(onValueUpdated);
    }
}
```

Parent's FXML :

```xml
<CharacteristicBar fx:id="courageBar" onBarValueChanged="#handleChangeCou" 
GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
```

Handler in parent's controller:

```java
    @FXML
    public void handleChangeCou(ValueUpdatedEvent event){
        System.out.println(event.getValue());
    }
```

Still, my event handler isn't called.

Do you guys have any clue on how to hook my handler with the event system ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the signatures of the methods related to the `onBarValueChanged` property in `CharacteristicBar`? WHat's the signature of  `handleChangeCou` in the controller class?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @fabian I just updated my post with the code of the handler in parent's controller. And I don't know how to specify the signature of the method expected by the onBarValueChanged property, do I have to declare it in the event definition ?

Comment: @Slaw You should be able to reproduce my situation with the code I provided

Comment: Maybe I could, if I wrote half of the code—but there's no guarantee what I come up with will represent your problem. You're attempting to set a property on `CharacteristicBar` but you don't even show that class. Note that, for instance, when you use `<Button onAction="#someMethod"/>` you are setting the `ButtonBase#onAction` property which holds an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, the implementation of which will invoke the `someMethod` method of the controller instance via reflection.

Comment: I just updated my post with the child component's controller class.
Ok I think I get your point, thank you. But in that case, why use the event mecanism and not juste call the eventhandler in the child instead of firing the event ?

Comment: @Ombrelin For `FXMLLoader` to recognize the `onXyz` attribute and use and event handler, the class corresponding to the fxml element type needs to contain a property with this name. Compare the situation for your class with the situation for [`Button.onAction`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty). Iirc the property itself is not required, but the setter (`public void setOnBarValueChanged(EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent>)`) and getter (`public EventHandler<ValueUpdatedEvent> getOnBarValueChanged()`) need to be there.

Comment: The method in the controller class, referenced by `"#..."` in the FXML file, is the _implementation_ of the `EventHandler`, but the handler still needs to be hooked into the event-dispatching system. You can look at the implementation of, for instance, the aforementioned `onAction` property to see an example of this. That said, I'm slightly confused about your setup. Is `CharacteristicBar` supposed to be the view or the controller—or both (e.g. `fx:root`)? And what is `Component`, your own class or one from e.g. AWT?

Comment: I updated my post with the progress made thanks to you guys ! @Slaw as you adviced, I looked into the ButtonBase source code to check how the onAction property was implemented but I can only see the declaration, getters and setters of the event handler, I can't understand where it is wired with the event system.
To answer your question, ```CharacteristicBar ``` is the """controller""" even if it's a node because that's the only way I found to create FXML enabled reusable UI components.

Comment: If you look at the initialization of the `onAction` field, you'll see it uses an anonymous implementation of `ObjectPropertyBase`. In that class they override the `invalidated()` method and call [`Node#setEventHandler(EventType,EventHandler)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)).

Comment: Thank you a lot, I followed your explanation. But now it throws me the following error when the event is fired : "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EventType "ValueUpdated"with parent "EVENT" already exists"
Do you have any idea where I could be wrong

Comment: Check out the implementations of the various event classes in JavaFX. They all store the possible `EventType`s related to the event in public static final fields.

Comment: Your were right, I updated my event with a static field and the error is gone.
However, my handler isn't called when the event is fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the custom event to work but instead I used properties to achieve my goal. Maybe it's intendend this way in JavaFX